# Javascript document write

Tags: javascript

How do I get this javascript to populate the textarea?

```
<body onload="form1.submit();"><div align="center">Loading...</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= g_page_site_actual %>/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= g_page_site_actual %>/js/jquery.wordstats.js"></script> <!-- core code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= g_page_site_actual %>/js/jquery.wordstats.en.js"></script> <!-- English stop words -->
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var count = 20;
            $.extend($.wordStats.stopWords, {'retrieved': true, '2007': true});
            $.wordStats.computeTopWords(count);
            var msgcounttext1 = '<%=completehtml%>'
            for(var i = 0, j = $.wordStats.topWords.length; i < j && i <= count; i++) {
               msg += $.wordStats.topWords[i].substring(1) + ', ';
            }
            {
            document.form1.textarea.value = document.write(msgcounttext);
            }
            $.wordStats.clear();
        });
        </script>
<div id="content" class="hidden"><%=completehtml%>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="test.asp">
        <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this javascript throw an exception.  At a quick glance I would suggest removing the document.write(...

Comment: i.e.document.form1.textarea.value = msgcounttext;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
document.form1.textarea.value= msgcounttext;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sample of a JQuery function to do that...

```
$('a').click(function()  
{ 
   $('#textarea').val('Insert this into the Text Area'); 
   //this puts the 'Insert this..' into the text area with the id 'textarea'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `document.write` method isn't used that way, you can just assign the value to the property. You can also use the jQuery `val` method to set the text.

Besides, you use three different variables in the code, which I think should be the same:

```
var msg = '<%=completehtml%>';
for(var i = 0, j = $.wordStats.topWords.length; i < j && i <= count; i++) {
  msg += $.wordStats.topWords[i].substring(1) + ', ';
}
$('#textarea').val(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides not having a variable named `msgcounttext`, get rid of the `document.write` call.